# Position of linking verb "are" in a question

Tags: verbs, questions

**EDITED:**
Are the following sentences correct in correctly positioning the linking verb **are**?

1. What different devices are used in this type of setting?
2. What are the different devices that are used in this type of setting?

**I am asking this to confirm if they mean the same?**

**EDITS** after @Kris 's comment

1. What different devices are used in this type of setting?
2. What are the different devices used in this type of setting?

Comment: Why do you think they are not? What has 'linking verb' to do with the examples, and with your question?

Comment: @ Kris Please see my edits

Comment: You should omit 'that are' in the second sentence for better/ correct comparative parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the assumption that both sentences are grammatically correct, I've got the gut feeling that they mean something slightly different.

*What **different** devices **are** used... ?* makes me think that the person is asking what devices may be used other than devices previously mentioned.

*What **are** the **different** devices that are used... ?* on the other hand could just mean that the person knows that different (i.e. various) devices are used in that type of setting, and would like to be given a list of them.

Comment: +1, in the first sentence, it is unclear as to whether *different* is a synonym for *other* or *various*. Presumably, though, this would not really be an issue if given context.

Comment: @Cameron. You're right as to the matter being unclear. I feel that "different" in the first sentence is synonymous to "other", whereas "various" would be the synonym in the second usage. However, you're right again in saying that the context would make things easier.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, these questions are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Per OP's Edit-2:

I think the two sentences are grammatically correct and identical.

If there is a difference in meaning, it is due to the status of the word '*different*' and **not the position of the verb**.  (I strongly suspect the definite article to be the culprit.)

As others have already stated, in the first case, the word '*different*' becomes rather precariously positioned: it could be understood as either 'various' as intended, or as 'other'.

The first sentence's construction being thus ambiguous, it may be avoided.